# Use of groupby as well as comparing & accessing against dicts?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Trying to better understand accessing data from dicts, comparing item from one dict to see if it exists in another dict to then assign a value depending on if it is found or not.  Also trying to use groupby to organize things.

Lets say I have the following "inventory.csv":

```
sku,item,category,price
111,apple,fruit,1.00
222,orange,fruit,1.25
333,lettuce,veggie,1.50
444,carrot,veggie,1.75
```

And I have the following "saleprice.csv":

```
sku,item,price
222,orange,1.00
444,carrot,1.50
```

My code attempt is as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import groupby
import csv

readInv = csv.DictReader(open('inventory.csv'))
inventory = {}
for row in readInv:
    key = row.pop('sku')
    if key in inventory:
        pass
    inventory[key] = row
print (inventory)
categories = inventory.items()

readSale = csv.DictReader(open('saleprice.csv'))
saleprice = {}
for row in readSale:
    key = row.pop('sku')
    if key in saleprice:
        pass
    saleprice[key] = row

for key, group in groupby(categories, lambda x: x['category']):
    print ("New Price by Category: " + key + "\n")
    for category in group:
        sku = category['sku']
        item = category['item']
        if sku in saleprice:
            price = saleprice['price']
        else:
            price = category['price']

    print ('Item:     {0}, SKU:      {1}, Price:      {2}').format(item, sku, price)
```

My first issue appears to be I am failing in my use of "groupby". As I keep getting errors related to "must be integers, not str".

I hoped my result would be something like:

```
New Price by Category: fruit
Item:   apple, SKU:    111, Price:    1.00
Item:   orange, SKU:    222, Price:     1.00

New Price by Category: veggie
Item:   lettuce, SKU:    333, Price:    1.50
Item:   carrot, SKU:    444, Price:    1.50
```

If I were to do this right it would see that sku 222 exists in saleprice dict and would use that price (1.00) to set the price variable.  Similarly for sku 444.

sku 111 and 333 do not exist in salesprice dict so it should use the price from inventory.

I could definitely use the knowledge of others to help understand how to correctly use "groupby" in this case. As well as then doing the appropriate checks to determine what the value should be assigned to "price".

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator


InvReader = csv.DictReader(open('inv.txt'))
SaleReader  = csv.DictReader(open('saleprice.txt'))

dictSaleReader = list(SaleReader)
updatedinv = []

for Invline in InvReader: 
    print Invline
    IsMatch=False
    for SalseLine in dictSaleReader:        
        if Invline['sku'] == SalseLine['sku']: # if a matching Item found in saleprice update price
            Invline['price']=SalseLine['price']
            updatedinv.append((Invline))
            IsMatch=True
    if IsMatch==False:
        updatedinv.append((Invline))

for category, group in itertools.groupby(updatedinv, key=operator.itemgetter('category')):
     print ("\nNew Price by Category: " + category + "\n")
     for category in group:
         print ('Item:     {0}, SKU:      {1}, Price:      {2}').format(category['item'], category['sku'], category['price'])
```

Output

```
New Price by Category: fruit

Item:     apple, SKU:      111, Price:      1.00
Item:     orange, SKU:      222, Price:      1.00

New Price by Category: veggie

Item:     lettuce, SKU:      333, Price:      1.50
Item:     carrot, SKU:      444, Price:      1.50
```